# How to group by column with same data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I have these 4 columns

1. id_date(int)
2. kpi(varchar)
3. attributte1(varchar)
4. amount(float)

in a table that looks like this:

| id_date | kpi | attribute1 | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | One | Three | 3 |
| 202101 | One | Three | 2 |
| 202102 | Two | Four | 5 |
| 202102 | Two | Four | 1 |

and I'm trying to group it by id_date, sum all amounts and have this as result

| id_date | kpi | attribute1 | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | One | Three | 5 |
| 202102 | Two | Four | 6 |

Tried the sum and group by function on my query but it's reflecting same results. Any idea on how to achieve this?

```
select  
    id_date, kpi, attributte1, 
    sum(amount) 
from 
    dual 
group by 
    id_date, kpi, attributte1, amount
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add in your query that's not giving you the results you expect?

Comment: done, i was grouping amount field but your answer now gave me what i was expecting, thanks!! @devlincarnate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the fields that aren't being aggregated:

```
SELECT id_date, kpi, attribute1, SUM(amount) as amount FROM mytable GROUP BY id_date, kpi, attribute1
```

Answer (score 1):

1st way

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id_date, 
    kpi,
    attribute1,
    SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id_date ORDER BY id_date) AS Amount
FROM
    myTable_data
```

2nd way: this is my preferred way as I partition by id_date and by base on partition by I assign a raw number to avoid duplication.

```
SELECT 
    A.id_date,
    A.kpi,
    A.attribute1,
    A.amount
FROM
    (SELECT 
         id_date,
         kpi,
         attribute1,
         SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id_date ORDER BY id_date) AS Amount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_date ORDER BY id_date) AS [rowNum]
     FROM     
         myTable_data) AS A
WHERE 
    A.rowNum = 1
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable_data
(
    id_date int,
    kpi varchar(10),
    attribute1 varchar(10),
    amount float
)

INSERT INTO myTable_data  
VALUES (202103, 'One', 'Three', 3),
       (202101, 'One', 'Three', 2),
       (202102, 'Two', 'Four', 5),
       (202102, 'Two', 'Four', 1),
       (202101, 'One', 'Three', 3)
```

Result:

[image: Answer]

Comment: @Renata Esquivel did you able to find what you were looking for from these answers ?